# How do I add values from custom fields in Admin to database?

Tags: magento-1.9, product-attribute

I've added some fields in Magento's `System > Configuration` which are now appearing like I want them to. However I can't find any information on how to insert the new values into the database. Can you guide me towards that?

Here's the code I've added so far

**app/code/local/Addrates/Updaterates/etc/adminhtml.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <acl>
    <resources>
      <admin>
        <children>
          <system>
            <children>
              <config>
                <children>
                  <Addrates>
                    <title>Update Rates</title>
                    <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                  </Addrates>
                </children>
              </config>
            </children>
          </system>
        </children>
      </admin>
    </resources>
  </acl>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Addrates/Updaterates/etc/system.xml**

```
<config>
    <sections>
         <sales>
            <groups>
                <newgroup translate="label" module="sales">
                    <label>Prices</label>
                    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                    <sort_order>250</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields>
                        <Gold1 translate="label">
                            <label>Gold Per Gram - 18kt</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                             <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </Gold1>
                        <Gold2 translate="label">
                            <label>Gold Per Gram - 20kt</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </Gold2>
                        <Gold3 translate="label">
                            <label>Gold Per Gram - 22kt</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>3</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </Gold3>
                        <Gold4 translate="label">
                            <label>Gold Per Gram - 24kt</label>
                            <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno</source_model>
                            <sort_order>4</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>0</show_in_store>
                        </Gold4>
                    </fields>
                </newgroup>
            </groups>
        </sales>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Apart from this I added some php code too **app/code/local/Addrates/Updaterates/Model/Observer.php**

```
<?php
    class Magentotutorial_Configviewer_Model_Observer {
        const FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG = 'showConfig';
        const FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG_FORMAT = 'showConfigFormat';

        private $request;

        public function checkForConfigRequest($observer) {
            $this->request = $observer->getEvent()->getData('front')->getRequest();
            if($this->request->{self::FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG} === 'true'){
                $this->setHeader();
                $this->outputConfig();
            }
        }

        private function setHeader() {
            $format = isset($this->request->{self::FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG_FORMAT}) ?
            $this->request->{self::FLAG_SHOW_CONFIG_FORMAT} : 'xml';
            switch($format){
                case 'text':
                    header("Content-Type: text/plain");
                    break;
                default:
                    header("Content-Type: text/xml");
            }
        }

        private function outputConfig() {
            die(Mage::app()->getConfig()->getNode()->asXML());
        }
    }
?>
```

PackageName/Namespace is `Addrates` and Module name is `Updaterates`. The 4 Fields are showing under sales field in admin. What next?

Comment: Google product options. You can do this without any code.

Comment: @ProxiBlue. Can You Please Elaborate Or Give Any LInk.

Comment: http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-product-option-and-its-use-case-in-magento/

Comment: The above given code is correctly working. I just want their values for further calculation.

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood your question. So all you want is to get the values from the admin populated fields?

Comment: @ProxiBlue, Yes, I create some fields, add them to database. Now I want their values and values from product detail attributes. To calculate the price and display.